# Redirect command output to /dev/null

Tags: io-redirection

How can we redirect output of command to `/dev/null`?

I tried it with:

```
command > /dev/null
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `command 2>&1 > /dev/null`?

Comment: that work for me, what are you mean by "don't work"? Maybe you see the STRERROR, not the STROUTPUT.

Comment: that syntax I used won't work. @gio900

Comment: what command your are trying for `command > /dev/null`? what it outputs?

Comment: /usr/bin/amixer cset numid=28 118

Comment: @cuonglm tell that to the OP, He said it DID solve his problem. Reread the comments.

Comment: @YoMismo: No, it can be the command he ran success. Try `ls file-does-not-exist 2>&1 >/dev/null`.

Comment: @YoMismo Since the OP has not explained what command he is using and whether it is printing to stdout or stderr, cuonglm is quite right in pointing out that what you show can fail. Even if it works for this particular case, it might not for the next person to read your comment and it's good to mention this. On the other hand, your comment is way out of line. If that's how you're going to behave towards others, then please do stay away. Rudeness is not acceptable. You're welcome to participate and I hope you do, but only if you can be civil.

Comment: @Terdon there is a difference between **can fail** and **wrong**. (Someone erased that comment). Discrediting another one is not the way to go, correcting or improving is. As I stated in my previous (erased) comment no one (AFAIK) gets paid for answering and trying to help, you just do it in your spare time because you want to help. When someone (a few people that can be counted with one hand's fingers) doesn't like an aswer or comment because it is not PERFECT just down votes or discredits the comment, so don't worry about me you won't see any answer (good or bad) from me any more.

Comment: @YoMismo `command 2>&1 > /dev/null` doesn't work because the redirection is read from right to left so the `>/dev/null` is applied _before_ the `2>&1`. So yes, it is actually wrong. However, even if it weren't, that wouldn't give you the right to use the kind of language you did. I'll be sorry to see you go, you post good content, all you need to do is be civil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command had redirected standard output to `/dev/null`, but maybe the `command` printed to standard error instead of standard output, so you still see the text in terminal.

To redirect standard output and standard error to `/dev/null`, you need:

```
command >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Note that the order of redirection is *important*, swapping them to `2>&1 >/dev/null` won't work because standard error was redirected to standard output at the time when standard output still point to terminal, you still see the text in terminal if `command` write to standard error.